# Java, JDBC, GROUP BY ROLLUP

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, group-by

В 1С при обходе результата запроса можно обходить запрос иерархически. Каждый итоговый результат содержит кроме полей, еще и вложенный результат, который так же можно обойти в цикле.
Подозреваю, что в голом SQL ситуация аналогичная. 
Подскажите как грамотно в коде обойти результат запроса с использованием группировок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду, то что в 1С запрос может возвращать иерархический ответ - не одномерную плоскую структуру, а некую двумерную таблицу, то в *голом SQL*  такого нет.

SQL подчиняется правилам стандартной реляционной алгебры, где результатом операций над таблицами (реляциями в терминах реляционной алгебры) всегда являются только таблицы - то есть плоская структура данных.

В JDBC класс `ResultSet` (вернее интерфейс) описывает именно классическую плоскую таблицу.

В разных диалектах SQL есть вещи похожие на двумерные запросы или OLAP кубы, но в JDBC это все равно не поддерживается.